# Conditionally disable checkbox in jQuery return

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code;

```
var isEditable = !self.model.hasPrivilege("UPDATE_INFO") || !self.editInfo;

return "<input type='checkbox' name='flag' class='flag' />";
```

Now my question is while doing the return for the input, can I add condition for isEditable as part of the same `return "<input type='checkbox'`

Basically I want to return disabled checkbox if isEditable is false and vice-versa ?

Answer (score 2):

```
return '<input type="checkbox" ' + (isEditable ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '') + ' .../>';
```

Comment: a small correction :)

`return '<input type="checkbox" ' + (!isEditable ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '') + ' .../>';`

He wants to disable if `isEditable` is `false`

Answer (score 0):

I think if this is jQuery, you can make it more clear like this:

```
var isEditable = !self.model.hasPrivilege("UPDATE_INFO") || !self.editInfo, 
    $checkBox = $("<input />", {
        type : "checkbox",
        name : "flag",
        class : "flag",
        disabled : !isEditable // condition to make the returned checkbox disabled
    });

return $checkBox;
```

this way, even if want to bind some events to the returned checkbox element, you can do that via adding another key to the second parameter object like:

```
$checkBox = $("<input />", {
    type : "checkbox",
    name : "flag",
    class : "flag",
    disabled : !isEditable, // condition to make the returned checkbox disabled,
    click : doSomething // attached some event
});
```